# How to use an html button to approve and reject list items?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I have taken two html buttons by just adding some html code into the "edit source" option of a list and I want it to be like when I am clicking it,it should approve and reject all the items in the list.
[image]

i want to do it using javascript if possible.
 What do I need to do?

Comment: Have you taken HTML button in a list or is it a dataview, listview or some jqgrid showing list items.

Comment: I have directly edited the Edit source option and given simple code to add html button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with javascript, here is some finished example for your problem:
http://spjsblog.com/2012/01/12/approve-multiple-documents-or-list-items-in-one-operation-with-client-side-code/

Or a more advanced solution with a button in the ribbon: 
http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.ch/2011/05/sharepoint-2010-approvereject-multiple.html

Comment: I want it on clicking a custom html button, is it possible?